# creating xml from csv file using shell script

Tags: bash, unix, sh, ksh

Aim : To create a xml file from the csv file

I am trying to create a xml file from the csv file, the xml contains header, footer and body.

I have create 3 different functions.

Input csv file

```
name,value,amt,position,qnty
abc,2,3,4,5
cde,7,8,9,10
abc,12,13,14,15
cde,7,8,9,10
```

Code to create xml from above csv file

```
  #!/usr/bin/sh

  FILENAME=$1
   #create body of xml file
   createBody()
   {
    echo ${FILENAME}

    while read var
    do
       filename=`echo $var | sed 's/ /_/g'`
       echo "<abc:archivingGroup xc:value=\"$var\">" >> ${filename}_Fixings.xml
      #create files for each unique group from groups.txt file
       grep $var ${FILENAME} > $filename.txt
      #traverse each file and create a separate xml file for each group
       while IFS=\; read a b c d e
       do
           TEST=$(cat <<EOF
                  <abc:index xc:value="$b">
                   </abc:index>
                    )
            echo $TEST >>  ${filename}_Fixings.xml
       done < $filename.txt
       rm $filename.txt
       echo "</abc:archivingGroup>" >> ${filename}_Fixings.xml
     done < Groups.txt

    }

  #header is common is all files
   createHeader()
       {
        filename=$1
        Header=$(cat << EOF
            <abc:Main>
            <abc:sub>
            <abc:head>
       )

     echo $Header > ${filename}_Fixings.xml

   }

  #footer is common in all files
  createFooter()
   {
      filename=$1;
      Footer=$(cat <<EOF
              </abc:Main>
              </abc:sub>
              </abc:head>
        )
     echo $Footer >> ${filename}_Fixings.xml
   }


  createarchFile()
  {
   IFS=\|
   #creates the unique groups (abc,cde as per above file)
   awk -F";" '{print $1}' ${FILENAME} | sed 1d | sort | uniq > Groups.txt
    #add header to each file, each uniq group is treated as a separate file
    while read var
    do
      filename=`echo $var | sed 's/ /_/g'`
      createHeader $filename
    done < Groups.txt

    #create body for all the files , header for all the files is appended above
    createBody

    #add footer to each file,each uniq group is treated as a separate file
    while read var
    do
      filename=`echo $var | sed 's/ /_/g'`
      createFooter $filename
    done < Groups.txt
  }
  createarchFile
```

The code above creates a xml file by taking csv as input

1. it takes the unique names from the file and stores in Groups.txt file
2. creates xml for all the groups available in Groups.txt
3. Traverse thru each group file and create header
4. Traverse thru each group file and create body
5. Traverse thru each group file and create footer

Is this the right approach or is there any other way to create a xml?

Comment: For a start, you might want to fix the quoting errors. http://shellcheck.net/ can give you detailed diagnostics.

Comment: I don't see a specific question. This seems more suitable for [codereview.se]

Comment: ... But broadly speaking; no, this is not a good match for shell script. This looks like it wants to be rewritten in Awk or maybe a few short and decisive `sed` scripts.

Comment: This is a job for a language that has both proper CSV and XML libraries.

Comment: Don’t understand why -1 , this is a working code and just a suggestion being asked , don’t know why it’s rated -1 :)

Comment: Well. In my firm we don’t have permissions to have any such libraries or use such language actually , and this is only way we could do it . And my question is whether this needs to be cleaned up further or not ?

Comment: @tripleee would you have any inputs for that . I would try to use that approach . Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming the -1 is because this is not a good SO question. This is a question that is primarily opinion based. It is also too broad for a good answer. Furthermore, your specific question can be answered with a simple "Yes" or a "No" (Where a "yes" is too small for an answer, and the "No" would be pretty broad to elaborate further). I also feel that it's unlikely to help anyone in the future as the usecase is pretty specific to your needs. Lastly, there is a separate Stackexchange site for Code Review which is really what this question boils down to.

Answer (score 0):

Using `printf` to fill in the values could be a cleaner option.

Build the first tag on the outer loop as

`first_tag='<abc:archivingGroup xc:value="%s">
    %s
</abc:archivingGroup>'
var='some_filename'
first_tag=$(printf "$first_tag" "$var" "%s")`

first_tag will contain

`<abc:archivingGroup xc:value="some_filename">
        %s
</abc:archivingGroup>`

Use that formatting string on inner loop as

```
#format element including placeholder for next element (if any)
ele='<abc:index xc:value="%s" />
    %s'
ele=$(printf "$ele" "$b" "%s")
# add to first_tag 
first-tag=$(printf "$first_tag" "$ele" "%s")
```

result

`<abc:archivingGroup xc:value="some_file_name"> 
        <abc:index xc:value="abc" />
        %s 
        </abc:archivingGroup>`

As long as there's a placeholder, you can add more elements.